# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a problem 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface

I have protobuf-2.5.0.jar in hbase lib and hadoop share common

Comment: Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the hbase-protocol library.

Comment: for me after adding this with HBase version 1.1 it's still needs more class to run, so just to update you guys once adding hbase-protocal be sure about the compatible versions too.

Comment: Hi @Codersfree can you please update this I have this error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder  What should I do so I could add this jar?

Comment: Hi @IndrajeetGour can you please update this I have this error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder What should I do so so I get rid of this error? Thanks